# React Testing Library and jest to mock custom Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am using React Testing Library and Jest to test React component which is using a custom Hook internally.
Have mocked the custom hook using

```
jest.mock('path/to/custom/hook', {
  someMethod: jest.fn()
})
```

Now in my the test cases, I am able to check if someMethod has been invoked or not on some action. But I also need to check a event which is written inside the actual someMethod written in custom Hook.

So the query is how to invoke both *mockedMethod* and the *actualMethod* here.

If not what is the best way to test such cases.

Comment: From my understanding, unit test is supposed to be test separately which means you might have to test your custom hook & your component using this hook separately